# Magento | How to send order email copy to the Customer Group email

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php, order-email

I added a field to set email address for each Customer Group No  need when the customer place an order send order email copy to his Group email.

Thanks to help me in this point...

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` class via the

> Magento_root/app/code/local/Mage

directory or rewrite it in your custom extension.

You set two tags to this question:

**magento-1.9** and **magento-1.8**

So if you are using Magento 1.9.1.0 or newest, then you need to add some code to the `queueNewOrderEmail` function otherwise into the `sendNewOrderEmail` function.

Please find the following line of code:

```
if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest())
```

and add the following code into the **else** statement:

```
$customerGroup = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($this->getCustomerGroupId());
if ($customerGroup->getEmail()) {
    $copyTo[] = $customerGroup->getEmail(); // getting value from your custom field
}
```

it should look like this:

```
if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
    $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
    $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
} else {
    $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
    $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
    $customerGroup = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($this->getCustomerGroupId());
    if ($customerGroup->getEmail()) {
        $copyTo[] = $customerGroup->getEmail();
    }
}
```